# Image Resize Command Issue in Magento 2.2.X

Tags: magento2.2, command-line, image-resize

I have Magento 2.2.x running website which is having more than 50K products and each product has up to 27 additional Images. 
When we run resize command (bin/magento catalog:images:resize), it takes approx 8-10 hours to execute it completely. 8-10 hrs is not acceptable anymore for resize and also it takes more load on server/sql.

Is there any way where we can resize images for some range of products or specific products (i.e product range or Limit)?

your help is really appreciated and we value your time.

Thanks!!